# Perform selector not calling in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created custom class for showing alert controller and defined action that need to be performed on click. When I am calling that function from other class, alert is shown, however when I clicked on Okay button perform selector is not been called. Below are both the function.

```
VFSCCocoaUtils.sharedInstance.createCommonAlert(mainTitle: kNoSimCardTitle, mainMessage: kNoSimCardMessage, subTitle: kOkButtonTitle, callBackName: #selector(self.getName), completionHandler: {( alertView) in
    self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
})


func createCommonAlert(mainTitle : String , mainMessage : String , subTitle : String, callBackName : Selector , completionHandler: @escaping (UIAlertController) -> ()) {

    let selector: Selector = callBackName
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title:mainTitle, message:mainMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: subTitle, style: .default, handler: { (alertView) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.perform(selector)
        }
    }))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completionHandler(alertView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace #selector(self.getName) with #selector(ClassName.getName). You need to mention the name of the class instead of self while creating a selector.

Comment: I have mention that #selector(VFSCSettingsViewController.getName), however it didn't work.

Comment: Why have you used the selector approach instead of passing a closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector is supposed to be performed on an instance of the class it belongs to, not on another class. You will need to modify the creation of the alert as follows:

```
func createCommonAlert(mainTitle : String , mainMessage : String , subTitle : String, callBackName : Selector, instance: NSObject , completionHandler: @escaping (UIAlertController) -> ()) {

    let selector: Selector = callBackName
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title:mainTitle, message:mainMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: subTitle, style: .default, handler: { [weak instance](alertView) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            instance?.perform(selector)
        }
    }))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completionHandler(alertView)
    }
}
```

And then call this as follows:

```
VFSCCocoaUtils.sharedInstance.createCommonAlert(mainTitle: kNoSimCardTitle, mainMessage: kNoSimCardMessage, subTitle: kOkButtonTitle, callBackName: #selector(VFSCSettingsViewController.getName), instance: self, completionHandler: {( alertView) in
    self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: Not a great idea to pass the self as a parameter because you will end up increasing the reference count of self by 1 as its held strongly. Use weak self and make NSObject optional that should do the same thing but with little more caution

Comment: @SandeepBhandari You are right! I am modifying the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: Finally because you are passing the instance of VC as param and calling perform selector on instance you passed VFSCSettingsViewController.getName is not needed you can simply say getName :)

Comment: Thanks to every one a healthy conversation, just one things, is there any better way to do this, please suggest, so that It will be help full to other developer.